# Java - change JTextField using separate ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, jtextfield

I have two classes, A and B.

Class A has a JTextField, and a private variable of class B. 
Class B implements ActionListener.

Class A and B are in separate files. 
Can I access the JTextField from class B through the ActionListener or is there a way (it is a requirement that I cannot have class B contained in A) I can do it? I've been searching and I haven't found a solution yet.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: For better help & sooner, consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: If `B` is registered as a `ActionListener` against `A.textField`, then yes.  The `ActionEvent` provides access to the `source` of the event, which will be the `JTextField` in `A` ... assuming `B` is registered of course.  The question is, should you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class B's actionPerfored method, you can access the source of the event through ActionEvent argument:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    JTextField field = (JTextField)e.getSource();//Now should represent the JTextField in class A
}
```

You can then perform actions on the JTextField. I would be wary when using class B as an ActionListener for other components though as this would throw an Exception if the source is not a JTextField.

Answer (score 0):

You could use event.getSource to access your component,

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
  JTextField registeredComponent = (JTextField)evt.getSource(); 
  // dangerous cast required 
}
```

or you could write a custom Observer Pattern implementation if you have to have to access different component types from your listener.

For example a customized EventObject implementation which includes a generic type of the source component.

```
public void actionPerformed(CustomEvent customEvt)
{
T registeredComponent = customEvt.getSource(); //generic getSource
}
```

Just take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern